# Creating a parquet file with StreamingFileSink in java

Tags: java, architecture, apache-flink, software-design

I'm aiming to convert the messages I received from kafka to parquet file here, but I could be wrong. Would you help me with this topic?

```
   private static SinkFunction<String> createFileSink(String outputPath) {
        final StreamingFileSink<String> sink = StreamingFileSink
                .forRowFormat(new Path(outputPath), new SimpleStringEncoder<String>("UTF-8"))
                .withRollingPolicy(
                        DefaultRollingPolicy.builder()
                                .withRolloverInterval(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15))
                                .withInactivityInterval(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))
                                .withMaxPartSize(1024 * 1024)
                                .build())
                .build();

        return sink;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [bulk-encoded-format](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/streamfile_sink/#bulk-encoded-formats) for writing Parquet. RowFormat is used for writing text, csv, json, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your return. I need to use the with .RollingPolicy part, but I see that this is not possible with .forBulkFormat. Do you have any comments about this?

Comment: Hi @Emsal. As we can see in the documentation (link above): Bulk Formats can only have `OnCheckpointRollingPolicy`, which rolls (ONLY) on every checkpoint.